# Tallying the numbers into bins using hist function

Tags: r, count, histogram

I want to tally the numbers in a vector into custom bins.
Suppose my custom bins are: `[-Inf, -1), [-1, 0), [0, 1.5)` and `[1.5, Inf)`. 
And the vector I want to classify is `c(.5, 2)`.

Basically what I want is the result of this:

```
hist(x = c(.5,2), breaks = c(-1000, -1, 0, 1.5, 1000), plot = FALSE)$count

[1] 0 0 1 1
```

Clearly, this will give an error if the vector is out of boundaries:

```
hist(x = c(.5, 2, 1001), breaks = c(-1000, -1, 0, 1.5, 1000), plot = FALSE)$count

Error in hist.default(x = c(0.5, 2, 1001), breaks = c(-1000, -1, 0, 1.5,  : 
  some 'x' not counted; maybe 'breaks' do not span range of 'x'
```

And the following code is surprisingly not working:

```
hist(x = c(.5,2), breaks = c(-Inf, -1, 0, 1.5, Inf), plot = FALSE)$count

[1] 2 0 0 0
```

Possibly I can use `findInterval` function, but I don't want to use it because the code will be longer and there is a possibility of empty bins and I want to know them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
x <- c(5,2)
table(cut(x = x,
            breaks = c(-Inf, -1, 0, 1.5, Inf)))
```

This would work too:

```
maxval <- 1.1*max(abs(x))
hist(x = c(.5,2), breaks = c(-maxval, -1, 0, 1.5, maxval),
       plot=FALSE)$counts
```

This is the original (perfectly sensible) suggestion:

```
hist(x = c(.5,2), breaks = c(-Inf, -1, 0, 1.5, Inf),
       plot=FALSE)$counts
```

The reason it goes wrong is that `hist.default()` tries to do some fancy stuff to add "fuzz" to the breaks, which turns out to be a disaster if `median(diff(breaks))` is infinite as in this case ...

```
## ....
diddle <- 1e-07 * stats::median(diff(breaks))   ## diddle -> Inf 
fuzz <- if (right) 
    c(if (include.lowest) -diddle else diddle, rep.int(diddle, 
        length(breaks) - 1))
else c(rep.int(-diddle, length(breaks) - 1), if (include.lowest) diddle else -diddle)
## fuzz ->  {-Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf}
fuzzybreaks <- breaks + fuzz  ## -> same as fuzz
h <- diff(fuzzybreaks)        ## -> {Inf NaN NaN NaN}
counts <- .Call(C_BinCount, x, fuzzybreaks, right, include.lowest)  ## -> { 2 0 0 0 }
## ....
```

The documentation for `hist` doesn't really say anything about this, except the cryptic note under "breaks": `These are the nominal breaks, not with the boundary fuzz.`

This is probably worth a note to the r-devel mailing list ...

Comment: Extra thanks for the last part, about why this anomaly happens.

Comment: Please note that the second approach (`maxval <- 1.1* ...`) does not work on edge cases e.g. `x <- c(2,.Machine$double.xmax)`. The first instead is perfectly fine.

Comment: @digEmAll : true, although hard to imagine that case coming up very often in practice ...